# can i simpilify this code im just triying to learn

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm triying to learn while loop and if statement so can i simplify this code?

```
y=10

i=10
while i > 0:
  if i==10 :
    print(y*"*")
    i -=1
  elif i== 9 :
    print(y*"*")
    i -=1
  elif i== 6 :
    print(y*"*")
    i -=1
  elif i== 5 :
    print(y*"*")
    i -=1
  else:
    print (x * "*")
    i -=1
```

Comment: All of the cases can be reduced to `if i in (10, 9, 6, 5)`

Comment: Take a look at the [for loop docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#forl)

Comment: @RobinDillen The `for` loop will not answer the question about the `if` conditions though

Comment: No you did that already! But i should have said to combine the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `if` and `elif` statements all do the same thing, you can condense them into one condition,

```
y = 10
x = 3
i = 10

values_1 = (5, 6, 9, 10)

while i > 0:
    if i in values_1:
        print(y * "*")
        i -= 1
    else:
        print (x * "*")
        i -= 1
```

Comment: Good job defining `values_1` outside of the loop. Now maybe take it one step further and use a set so this becomes O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: @DeepSpace With only four elements in `values_1`, I bet the code is faster keeping it as a tuple than it would be with a set. This is a case where I would keep the tuple, because of the small constant size.